# Importing data quick into R and exit

Tags: 16.04, clipboard, r

I got this problem:

Warning message:
In read.table("clipboard", header = T) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'clipboard'

I have:
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Any kind of help?

Thanks in advance!!!
Chitra

Comment: I don't understand the questions. Please add details and also fix the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to export your data into excel first, then, 
export the excel sheet to the csv (comma separated values) file,
then use read.csv(“your_file.csv”, header = T) rather than read.table.

Please make sure the last column on the csv file ends with the right format for Linux or you may experience the last column to be missed.

Cheers

Comment: Dear Malypetu, I have not the problem of .txt or .csv but the problem of quick import function of "clipboard". As long as windows concern that function was ok but after I switch to linux I discovered this problem.